# linq to sql outer left join with multiple join conditions

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-sql, code-behind

I have a two table that I need to join and select values from, the join needs to be left outer join. I am trying to use linq to sql but getting 0 instead of real values

**references table:**

```
refType varchar(250),
description varchar(250)
```

**presentationsType (another table of mine)**

```
id int
refType varchar(250),
OtherFundings varchar(250)
```

The query I am using is

```
string organization = (string)Session["organization"];
int FiscalYear = Int32.Parse((string)Session["fiscalyear"]);
string ReportingPeriod = (string)Session["reportingperiod"];

var presentationType = from pt in OCHART.References
                       join rf in OCHART.OCHART_PresentationTypes on pt.RefType equals rf.RefType into prt                                       
                       from x in prt.Where(prt2 => prt2.OrganizationName.Equals(organization) && prt2.ReportingPeriod.Equals(ReportingPeriod) && prt2.FiscalYear == FiscalYear).DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where pt.RefType.Equals("09-10.1b")                                          
                        orderby pt.RefOrder ascending
                        select new {
                              refType = pt.RefType, 
                              refName = pt.Description,
                              otherFundings = (x.Fundings == null ? 0 : x.Fundings), 
                              id = (x.id == null ? 0 : x.id)
                         };
```

But I am getting id = 0 and otherFunding = 0 despite having proper values in the second table. I am really unsure of what I am doing wrong.

Would appreciate a help.

Thanks.

Comment: I believe you can mark your own question for deletion since it poses no benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I hate it when I create a question after long time of breaking my head and than find a solution just right after it on my own.

Please dismiss the question, my problem was not linking proper fields for join.

Sorry again.

Comment: In that case, maybe share your own answer. It may help someone else :)